# C++ program crashes terminal--How do I debug this?

Tags: c++, terminal, serial-port, arduino

Don't ask me how--I haven't the slightest.

The following code crashes my terminal and any runtime analysis tool I use, while not raising any static checking tool warnings.  Valgrind, cppcheck, and gdb have done me little good.  g++ -Wall does not give me anything useful.

The goal of the code is to write a character to a audrino through a USB serial connection.  The audrino address is passed as the first argument.  A unsigned int is passed and is cast to a unsigned char.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char** argv){

  struct termios stdio;
  int tty_fd;

  unsigned char ctrlChar;
  unsigned int ctrlInt;

  tty_fd=open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
  tcgetattr(tty_fd, &stdio);
  cfmakeraw(&stdio);
  stdio.c_cc[VMIN]  = 1;
  stdio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
  tcsetattr(tty_fd,TCSANOW, &stdio);
  tcsetattr(tty_fd,TCSAFLUSH, &stdio);
  fcntl(tty_fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK);

  cfsetospeed(&stdio,B9600);            // 9600 baud
  cfsetispeed(&stdio,B9600);            // 9600 baud

  cout << "ready on " << argv[1] << endl;

  scanf("%u", ctrlInt);
  cout <<"recieved initial read.\n";
  while (ctrlInt < 256){
    ctrlChar = ((char) ctrlInt);
    cout << ctrlInt << ctrlChar << endl;
    write(tty_fd,&ctrlChar,1);
    cout << "sent to audrino.\n";
    scanf("%u", ctrlInt);
  }

  cout << "done!" << endl;

  close(tty_fd);
  return 0;
}
```

Now, in the offchance that this seems sane, I'll file a bug report.

Sys specs:  up to date Arch linux 64 bit, compiled with "g++ -g -Wall code.c"

Comment: Did you try to examine core dump?

Comment: It technically exits successfully, so I don't know how to pull a core dump out of it.  Programming for 5 years and I've never seen a program do this.  I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "crashed my terminal" you mean that the terminal stops working, than the reason is most probably that you are setting all kinds of flags to zero on your stdout (aka. your terminal). You are calling `tcsetattr()` and zero out basically all terminal control flags there are.

You should get the current terminal flags with `tcgetattr()`, modifiy the ones you want to modify, and then use that struct for the call to `tcsetattr()`. Not doing so is even [undefined behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/tcsetattr.html):

> The effect of `tcsetattr()` is undefined if the value of the `termios` structure pointed to by `termios_p` was not derived from the result of a call to `tcgetattr()` on `fildes`; an application should modify only fields and flags defined by this specification between the call to `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()`, leaving all other fields and flags unmodified.

Comment: Silly me assuming example code was good...I'll try this in the morning.

Comment: Likewise for the call to `fcntl(2)`—you should not just call `fcntl(..., F_SETFL, <flags>)`, but rather `fcntl(..., F_SETFL, <flags> | fcntl(..., F_GETFL))` to keep the previous flags and add the ones you want.

Comment: I have to report bad news.  While the terminal is no longer irrate, it is still unresponsive and in effect crashed.  This did not answer my question, but undoubtedly helped.  The code is updated above.

Comment: @Josh: You are still setting quite a few members of that struct to `0`. Do you really want to set all the flags stored in `c_iflags`, `c_oflags`, ... to zero? I'm no expert at termios, but setting all those flags to `0` (whatever that means) doesn't sound like a good idea to me...

Comment: I've been working on it.  Is there a good place for documentation?  I've updated the code again.

Comment: I found where the original example code came from -- wikibooks.  I flagged its contents for review.

Comment: Another update.  No terminal crashing, but there are still terminal issues.  Reads and writes are off during program execution.  Code has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

If you use linux, you can use `strace`

```
strace ./yourProgram
```

You can also debug the coredump file,

```
ulimit -c unlimited
g++ -g ...
```

than coredump file will be created when program crashes.

```
gdb ./yourProgram coredump
```

use `bt` command to look crash info.